# Deploy ASP.NET core to Azure Container Service (Swarm mode)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, azure-container-service

I've set up an Azure Container Service cluster, as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-deployment with SWARM. Then I've connect to it as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect.

I've installed docker for windows (I've shared drives) and the visual studio docker tools.

I've created the default ASP.NET Core app that has this dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0.1
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyTest.dll"]
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY $source .
```

I've changed it (because it doesn't do anything) to something that looks like :

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0.1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyTest.dll"]
```

Then, I've opened a command prompt and moved to my root folder and i've done :

```
set DOCKER_HOST = tcp://localhost:2375
docker version
```

(docker version is OK)

then :

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o out
docker build -t testaspnetcore .
```

then :

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 testaspnetcore
```

then :

```
docker ps
```

and I see the container in the list, but when I connect to my cluster ACS with SSH and I do

```
docker -H 172.16.0.5:2375 ps -a
```

I can't see my container in the cluster.

note : when I do `docker ps` on local, i can see in putty event log : `Forwarded port closed due to local error: Network error: Software caused connection abort`. Tried to turn of firewall, and many others things, but no results

How can I deploy to the swarm cluster my own image ?

Comment: Looks like your application crashed. You should see information in the logs. 'docker PS -a' will show you the id of the exited container. Then do 'docker  logs ID' to view the output.

Comment: it tells me : Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409. Does miss really the image microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0.1 the dotnet sdk ? How can I add it ?

Comment: I've edited my question with new infos, with another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-docker-swarm

With respect to your Putty problem it might me that you have Docker running on your client machine thus you have a port conflict. You can change the client port to something different to avoid this clash.

Comment: Docker for Windows was running on my machine. Killed it and putty worked without the conflict. Thanks!